# Silverlight, connecting service.cs and XAML.cs for database

Tags: silverlight

I've found a sample showing how to connect to SQL server (a local MDF), but it uses databinding, how can I use SQL in the normal way (insert, select, update, delete..., sqldatareader, without binding), I think all SQL staff should be performed in service.cs, so how can I use SQL from my XAML.cs? here is the service code:

and here service.cs:

```
public class ServiceCustomer : IServiceCustomer
{
    public clsCustomer getCustomer(int intCustomer)
    {
        SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection();
        DataSet ObjDataset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter objAdapater = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer where CustomerId=" + intCustomer.ToString());
        objConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ToString();
        objConnection.Open();
        objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
        objAdapater.SelectCommand = objCommand;
        objAdapater.Fill(ObjDataset);
        clsCustomer objCustomer = new clsCustomer();
        objCustomer.CustomerCode = ObjDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        objCustomer.Customer = ObjDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        objConnection.Close();
        return objCustomer;
    }
}
```

and my page.xaml.cs:

```
public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceCustomerClient obj = new ServiceCustomerClient();
        obj.getCustomerCompleted += new EventHandler<getCustomerCompletedEventArgs>(DisplayResults);
        obj.getCustomerAsync(1);
    }
    void DisplayResults(object sender, getCustomerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = e.Result;

    }
```

how can I insert a value into my dayabase right from my page.xaml.cs? how can I make a connection between service and xaml objects and functions?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Page.xaml.cs file is not autogenerated in a standard silverlight project (beyond it's initial creation via template), so any changes you make to the class will persist.

If your current project does some autogen of xaml classes then you can use the partial class feature of C# [Partial Classes in C# Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to add to the class without worrying that the autogen will remove your additions.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add another method within your service class that performs the insert, and then pass it the values from your form.

```
public class ServiceCustomer : IServiceCustomer
{
    public clsCustomer getCustomer(int intCustomer)
    {
      ...
    } 

    public void addCustomer(clsCustomer newCustomer)
    {
         //Code to add the customer to the database
    }
}
```

to call this from your code you could use the following code, all calls to the service in silverlight are Asynchronous calls therefore they are called in a seperate thread but since the following call has no return there is no need for a completed event handler.

```
public void foo
{
    clsCustomer cust = new clsCustomer();
    //Create your customer object here

    ServiceCustomerClient obj = new ServiceCustomerClient();

    obj.AddCustomerAsync(cust);
}
```

this function could then be called when ever you want to add a customer, E.g. when a button is clicked

```
public void somebutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      foo();
}
```

If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: thanks, but how can I call service functions from my XAML.cs? it is my main problem, there is an auto-generated file, I think my function should go there, but how? can you give me any tip around that? thanks again

Comment: Your xaml.cs is autogenerated at the start and that is where all of your code should go. i've updated my initial post to show how you could call your service method from the code behind file.